# Displaying time from timestamp in Unix, UTC in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, date, kotlin

I am working on a simple weather app and am trying to display time in the format "K:mm a" (eg. 6:30 AM). I am fetching a timestamp in Unix, UTC for the specified place a user searches for such as NYC. The timestamp looks something like 1624836905 and the time zone offset such as -14400. I have a function which adds the two up, converts it to milliseconds and should return the time in the format specified. The function is as follows:

```
fun dateTime(time: Int, zone: Int, format: String = "EEE, MMMM d K:mm a"): String {
        return try {
            val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(format)
            val netDate = Date((time.plus(zone)).toLong() * 1000)
            sdf.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
            sdf.format(netDate)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.toString()
        }
    }
```

And I call it such as:

```
sunriseTextView.text = dateTime(result2.lookup<Int>("daily.sunrise")[0], timeZone, "K:mm a")
sunsetTextView.text = dateTime(result2.lookup<Int>("current.sunset")[0], timeZone, "K:mm a")
```

The expected output is the sunrise/sunset time such as 6:01 AM and 9:05 PM. I am also rendering the current time at the specified place also obtained from the API. As follows:

```
dateView.text = dateTime(result2.lookup<Int>("current.dt")[0], timeZone)
```

Which outputs the current date and time at the place in the format "EEE, MMMM d K:mm a" (eg. Mon June 28 8:23 AM).

The current time is always correct, however, there is a problem with the sunrise and sunset times. If I input NYC, for example, the sunrise is 7:35 PM and sunset 10:39 AM. The sunrise and sunset for Tokyo, on the other hand, appears correct at 4:27 AM and 7:00 PM.

Clearly I am missing something as I know the API data is correct. I am looking for any suggestions, however, I would appreciate one which does not have API restrictions such as kotlinx-datetime which requires API 26.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar function in Python like this:

```
    def time(self, unix_time, time_zone):
        date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(unix_time + time_zone)
        return (datetime.strftime(date, '%I:%M %p'))
```

Which I call as follows:

```
WeatherApp.time_zone = self.weather_results['timezone_offset']
print(self.time_date(self.weather_results['current']['dt'], self.time_zone))
print('Sunrise: ' + self.time(self.weather_results['current']['sunrise'], self.time_zone))
print('Sunset: ' + self.time(self.weather_results['current']['sunset'], self.time_zone))
```

I am trying to get the same result in Kotlin. However comparing the outputs is as follows:

```
Location: Tokyo, Japan 
Current time and date: Tue, June 29 06:53 PM (same in Python and Kotlin from Asia/Tokyo, 1624960598 1624961970
32400)
Sunrise: 04:27 AM (as outputted in Python from 32400, 1624908462)
Sunset: 07:00 PM (as outputted in Python from 32400, 1624960847)
Sunrise: 4:27 AM (as outputted in Kotlin from Asia/Tokyo, 1624908467)
Sunset: 7:00 PM (as outputted in Kotlin from Asia/Tokyo, 1624960846)
---
Location: New York, United States
Current time and date: Tue, June 29 6:02 AM  (same in Python and Kotlin from America/New_York, 1624960973)
Sunrise: 05:27 AM (as outputted in Python from -14400, 1624958860)
Sunset: 08:31 PM (as outputted in Python from -14400, 1625013070)
Sunrise: 7:35 PM (as outputted in Kotlin from America/New_York, 1624923330)
Sunset: 10:39 AM (as outputted in Kotlin from America/New_York, 1624977548)
```

Comparing the timestamps shows that the data obtained from the API differs for some reason. I currently solved it by using a different API. I was using the One Call API by OpenWeather. I can't think of a reason why this is happening, however, by getting the timestamp from a different API the issue no longer persists.

Comment: I spent days thinking that it was the function. I trusted the API fully XD

Answer (score 4):

Since there's [API Desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table), you can use `java.time` with API versions below 26.

That means you don't have to rely on those outdated datetime classes, like `java.util.Date` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Your `fun` can be rewritten like this:

```kotlin
fun dateTime(time: Int, zone: String, format: String = "EEE, MMMM d K:mm a"): String {
    // parse the time zone
    val zoneId = ZoneId.of(zone)
    // create a moment in time from the given timestamp (in seconds!)
    val instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(time.toLong())
    // define a formatter using the given pattern and a Locale
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format, Locale.ENGLISH)
    // then make the moment in time consider the zone and return the formatted String
    return instant.atZone(zoneId).format(formatter)
}
```

Here's some example use in a simple `fun main()`:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val timestamp: Int = 1624836905 // your example epoch seconds
    // try two different zones
    val newYorkTime = dateTime(timestamp, "America/New_York")
    val tokyoTime = dateTime(timestamp, "Asia/Tokyo")
    // and print the results
    println(newYorkTime)
    println(tokyoTime)
}
```

Output of this example:

```
Sun, June 27 7:35 PM
Mon, June 28 8:35 AM
```

Please note that you could as well use an `offset: Int` instead of a `zone: String` if you simply want to provide an offset of *hours from UTC*. You would need to adjust two lines of this `fun` then:

```kotlin
fun dateTime(time: Int, offset: Int, format: String = "EEE, MMMM d K:mm a"): String {
    // parse the time zone
    val zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.ofHours(offset)
    // create a moment in time from the given timestamp (in seconds!)
    val instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(time.toLong())
    // define a formatter using the given pattern and a Locale
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format, Locale.ENGLISH)
    // then make the moment in time consider the zone and return the formatted String
    return instant.atOffset(zoneOffset).format(formatter)
}
```

Using that in a main like this

```kotlin
fun main() {
    val timestamp: Int = 1624836905
    
    val newYorkTime = dateTime(timestamp, -4)
    val tokyoTime = dateTime(timestamp, 9)
    println(newYorkTime)
    println(tokyoTime)
}
```

will produce the very same output.

In addition, the `Locale` used in the `DateTimeFormatter` could as well be a function argument in case you want to support different languages (this affects the names of months and days of week).

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast and thorough answer. I tried both of the options with the time zone offset as a string and as an int. I am, however, running into the same issue, that is, the current time, sunrise and sunset are correct for places to the East from the UTC, but places with negative offset have wrong times. Such as: 
Current time, NYC:
zone: America/New_York,
timestamp: 1624892520, 
time: Mon, June 28 11:02 AM,

Sunrise:
timestamp:1624836905, 
time: 7:35 PM,

Sunset:
timestamp: 1624891150, 
time: 10:39 AM

Comment: @Klariskao Can you describe the error in specific detail? I think I don't quite get what's going wrong in your situation. What does *wrong times* mean? Is it that sunset at 10:39 AM is wrong (looks like)? The problem is then the value you are receiving, because `1624891150` was definitely 10:39 AM in New York.

Comment: I posted a comment below which hopefully explains the issue. Turns out that the data from the API was not what I expected and therefore the outcome was wrong too. Thank you for your effort and answer. It works perfectly with data from a different API.